# is there an event on select "dropdown" event on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to add option on my dropdown select when user clicks the select element and dropdown selection appears.

the problem with using the `$(select).on('click',function(){});` code is that its not working properly on chrome (mac) and also gets triggered when the user select/clicks the options below.

I was also trying to use `change` but its only triggered when the option is actually selected/changed so its not an option too..

is there an alternative event for this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no cross browser approach to do this with native `<select>` What is your use case?

Comment: there probably isn't a reliable event listener for it. why not add it before it dropdowns? for e.g. add it in document.ready or everytime after `change`

Comment: Hi @charlietfl , I was trying to add option when user add a value from the other page..

e.g. I added a button "add new option" ( when clicked ) opens new page and fills up the form, so when completed, the newly added option is then added to the select dropdown ( which checks the database values via ajax )

Comment: So how are you passing data for the option to new page? And why wouldn't you be able to add it on page load?

Comment: ahh.. when I said opens a new page I meant "new tab" so the user wont have to close the current page..

Comment: So if that select exists already what prevents you adding the option as soon as button is clicked?

Comment: coz when the button is clicked, it just open a new tab and loads other page with form and he needs to fill the form first and then submit it.. so I want to do is.. when the user checks the select he can then see the newly added "option" which is added via other page with no direct connection from the first page where the "add new" button is located..

Comment: Ok so if you use ajax to load *"other page"* add the option in the ajax success callback perhaps

Comment: nope.. Im not using ajax to load the "other page" , I used ajax to get the available options from the database, which is added from the other page..

Comment: anyways thanks for your time, I think I'll just use dropdown library to make this work.